# JVM Heap issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jvm, heap-memory

I am doing a bit of research into the project setup I use in work.

I noticed quite a few apps seem to have memory leaks/heap issues. I noticed that when I start an application, it seems to jump from 1% heap used to 20% for the first 15 minutes, then it will start to level out and consistently use only about 1%.

```java
public void testPersist() {

    while (true) {

        List<TestModel> testModels = createTestModels();
        testModelManager.save(testModels);      
        testModels = null;

        ApplicationPerformanceSampler.sampleMemory();
    }
}

/**
 * @return
 */
private List<TestModel> createTestModels() {
    List<TestModel> testModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
        testModel.setTestString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
        testModels.add(testModel);
    }

    return testModels;
}
```

This is a sample app I made to just persist objects to a MySQL database using spring, hibernate and JPA.

```java
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void save(final T model) {
    LOG.debug("save model={}", model);
    em.persist(model);

    LOG.debug("model saved. id={}", model.getId());
}
```

I wrote a small class to sample memory as I was persisting because of the initial thought that the memory footprint was getting bigger as it persisted.

```java
 public static void sampleMemory() {

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        long maximumAllocatedMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
        long freeMemory = maximumAllocatedMemory - allocatedMemory;

        Double freeMemoryDouble = Double.valueOf(freeMemory);
        Double maximumAllocatedMemroryDouble = Double.valueOf(maximumAllocatedMemory);
        Double percentageFreeMemory = freeMemoryDouble / maximumAllocatedMemroryDouble * 100;

        ApplicationPerformanceStatus appStatus = determineAppStatus(percentageFreeMemory);

        Double usedHeap = 100 - percentageFreeMemory;
        LOG.info("usedHeap={}%, freeHeap={}%, appStatus={}", format(usedHeap), format(percentageFreeMemory),
                appStatus.getText());
}
```

However when I attached visualVM I saw the following?
**heap over 30 minutes**
[image: heap over 30 minutes]
Below I have included an example of some of the log messages (Each logged after 5000 records are persisted. I have seen and put into the logs, where I know garbage collection has taken place.

```
2019-10-02 10:58:37.035 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=9.14%, freeHeap=90.86%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:38.933 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=9.96%, freeHeap=90.04%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:40.226 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=10.92%, freeHeap=89.08%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:41.616 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=4.02%, freeHeap=95.98%, appStatus=OK
(Garbage collection)
2019-10-02 10:58:42.878 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=5.06%, freeHeap=94.94%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:44.215 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=5.96%, freeHeap=94.04%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:45.576 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=7.0%, freeHeap=93.0%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:47.001 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=8.04%, freeHeap=91.96%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:48.333 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=9.09%, freeHeap=90.91%, appStatus=OK
2019-10-02 10:58:49.651 INFO  [main] (ApplicationPerformanceSampler.java:52) - usedHeap=10.28%, freeHeap=89.72%, appStatus=OK
(Garbage collection)
```

I'm not quite sure where to go from here?

Comment: why do you think these are issues? It stabilised nicely, each GC cleared the unused objects (saw-tooth pattern) once the application finished starting up and warming up, what is left in its life is very little creation and very little GC. Seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: To be honest. I didn't know if it was a problem or not. I started investigating this "issue" on a short running app that's ran once a day, so it looked like this pattern was a problem. I didn't know how to word the question on google, so thought I'd ask it myself.

Comment: As a side question, why do you box your values to `Double` objects, instead of straight-forwardly using `double` values?

Comment: @Holger Sorry for late reply. I prefer to use the double class because it has helpful methods when dealing with other operations. valueOf() being an example here.

Comment: You only need the `valueOf` method *because* you can’t convert `long` to `Double` directly, so you’re solving a problem you wouldn’t have if you didn’t use it. If you used `double freeMemoryDouble = freeMemory, maximumAllocatedMemroryDouble = maximumAllocatedMemory, percentageFreeMemory = freeMemoryDouble / maximumAllocatedMemroryDouble * 100;` instead, it would do the same without needing a `valueOf` method and without boxing overhead. In fact, you wouldn’t even need these temporary variables, if you just declared `double freeMemory = maximumAllocatedMemory - allocatedMemory;`